# Partially deleting elements from a bytearray while adding to it from another thread

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety

I have bytearray object, two threads are accessing it, a producer and consumer.

The producer writes to the bytearray: `barr.extend(data)`

The consumer reads from the bytearray: `barr.find(...)`, `barr[x:y]`

The producer adds alot of data to the bytearray so I want to free up memory occasionally by `del barr[:last_read_pos]`

Is this operation thread safe?

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like you want a queue datastructure where you can efficiently add to the end and remove from the beginning. There is a thread-safe implementation in `queue.Queue`

Comment: queue is not good in my case, I need continuous datastructure that will hold byte stream

Comment: Why? From your example the producer sends chunks (`data`). Does the consumer have to find the data across chunk boundaries? Otherwise you can use a `threading.Lock` to synchronize access to your buffer

Comment: If the data i need to find will split across two chunks i will not be able to find it

Comment: (1) Continuous data structure and (2) The ability to delete parts of it, are things that usually don't go hand in hand. You can always reallocate data, but it typically ends up in a new position in memory, which also means that the data had to be copied to this new location

Comment: So the best way to do it is by using a temporary `bytearray` and `queue`, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Is this operation thread safe?"
"yes", but only due to the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock). It is actually unsafe up to the point that although it would work, it should not be done. Just use a Lock - it is painless enough.

Or, a queue, which is built for this: adding byte-object as Queue items, instead of extending a bytearray with then make your code at one time simpler and more efficient, as extending a bytearray involves copying the bytes around, realocating the whole array at times, and so on.

So - reading more carefully your requirements in the comments: since you want the continuous byte structure, a simple thing to do is to use the Queue to post bytes objects on the producer side, and assemble your continuous buffer on the consumer side.